# debug chef with an empty run list, what's the syntax?

Tags: debugging, chef-infra

A popular suggestion for debugging chef is to
debug chef with an empty run list, what's the syntax?

something like:
$ sudo chef-client -o "recipe[]"    ??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever suggested that to someone, but I would think `chef-client -o ''` should work. What are you trying to debug that you think an empty run list would help? Errors during initialization are usually pretty clear since they happen before you see much other output.

Comment: It's actually in the official Chef docs - https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html#empty-run-lists . It just makes stuff a bit clearer (particularly if you're new to Chef) if you have a config issue

Comment: The Chef docs should be considered, at best, general guidelines.